# Fixed header issue in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am facing fixed header issue in IE. Fixed header css is not working properly in IE.it is working in other browsers. only it is not worlinh in IE
Please help any one.i have css added by javascript.pls help anyone.

HTML:

```
  <div id="tab-1">
  <div class="loadedTable">   
    <table id="table-1">
    <caption> table</caption>
    <thead class="fixedHeader">
      <tr> 
        <th style="width:2%">header1</th>
        <th style="width:2%">header1</th>
        <th style="width:2%">header1</th>
        <th style="width:2%">header1</th>
        <th style="width:2%">header1</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>123456</td>
        <td>123456</td>
        <td>123456</td>
        <td>123456</td>
        <td>123456</td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>123456</td>
        <td>123456</td>
        <td>123456</td>
        <td>123456</td>
        <td>123456</td> 
      </tr><tr>
        <td>123456</td>
        <td>123456</td>
        <td>123456</td>
        <td>123456</td>
        <td>123456</td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>123456</td>
        <td>123456</td>
        <td>123456</td>
        <td>123456</td>
        <td>123456</td> 
      </tr>

    </tbody> 
    </table>  
    </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
    var wrapperCon= $('#wrapperCon');
    wrap.scroll(function(e){ 
        fixedHeader();          
    });

   variableHeight =  Math.abs(wrapperCon.offset().top - $('#tab-1 .loadedTable').offset().top)+19;
      function fixedHeader(){   
        $(document).find('.fixedHeader').each(function(){ 
            $(this).css('width', $(this).find('table').width());
        });
        var tabid = $(".ui-tabs-active").attr('aria-controls'),
            myTabsIdHeightt = $('#mytabsId').find('ul').height(),
            WidthDiv1Ht = $('#'+tabid).find('.WidDiv1').height();
            FinalHt = myTabsIdHeightt+WidthDiv1Ht+67;


        if(wrap.scrollTop() > variableHeight){ 
                if(ie){

                $(document).find('.fixedHeader').css({'position':'relative','top':(wrap.scrollTop()-FinalHt)+'px'});  
                }else
                {

                $(document).find('.fixedHeader').css({'position':'relative','top':(wrap.scrollTop()-FinalHt)+'px'}); 
                }
        }else{
            $(document).find('.fixedHeader').removeAttr('style');
        }           
    }
```

Comment: can you please make fiddle ? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yo49jsuo/

Comment: see your console there is error 'wrap is not defined' tell me where you define this 'wrap' variable ?

Comment: updated: https://jsfiddle.net/yo49jsuo/1/

Comment: now you are missing 'variableHeight'  , 'variableHeight' is not define

Comment: can you tell me what exactly do u want ?

Comment: because in your code you are using most of the Variable that not define like 'ie' , 'variableHeight' , 'wrap' etc

Comment: how to resolve that?

Comment: just tell me or give me any example that you want to do,i am facing troubling with your code

Comment: can u send me any example using fixed header for IE?

Comment: may be this link will help u http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/